# Calculate area overlap for pairs of polygons in matrix format in R

Tags: r, matrix, polygon, overlap

I am trying to calculate the area and percentage of overlap between polygons for multiple pairs. For example, I have 5 polygons and I want to calculate the area and percentage of overlap for each combination of pairs. Is there a way I can run a function including all polygons (shapefiles) and get a matrix output showing the values for each pair? I would like to get an output like this:

```
overlap    poly 1     poly 2    poly 3     poly 4 poly 5

poly 1

poly 2

poly 3

poly 4

poly 5
```

The formula I use to calculate percentage of overlap for a pair of polygons is the following:

```
AreaOverlap/(SQRT(AreaPolyA*AreaPolyB))
```

Thanks!

Comment: please provide some sample data.. (hint: use `dput()`)

Comment: What is the formatting of the polygone? x.y coordinates? or directly given area? need more information

Comment: @Mandar the different polygons are different shapefiles that I load into R, so in a coordinate system.

Comment: @Wimpel Can I provide sample data with dput() if the data I used are shapefiles I loaded into R?

Comment: @Stijn you have to create a minimal reproducible example, so loading your entire shapefiles is probably too much.. You can also link to your data if this is necessairy... My answer below will work if you load the shapefiles as separate polygons in an sf-object..  You will probabaly have to follow some tutorials on the package if you have not worked with it before.. for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/230161/129211

Comment: @Wimpel if this helps, here is a link to three shapefiles as an example. The shapefiles are animal home ranges and each shp contains three different polygons (50%, 75%, 95% kernel density probability). Ideally, I need only the overlap values for the same probabilities for the different shapefiles. So the overlap between the 95% polygons of the different shp, and same for 75% and 50%. But not between 50% and 95% for example.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fec5effe5ffe961c006dc51e5275697020190117140921/edf93f2129df9525f994664a405e8b8f20190117140921/528ff6

Comment: @Wimpel do you have any more suggestions how I can run a similar code, using the shapefiles?

Answer (score 9):

Without sample data, i think a possible solution can be:

**create some sample data**

```
library( sf)
#square of 2 x 2
pol = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(2,0), c(2,2), c(0,2), c(0,0))))
#add two more squares of 2 x 2
b = st_sfc(pol, pol + c(.8, .2), pol + c(4, .8))

plot(b)
```

[image]

**calculate overlapping area**

```
l <- lapply( b, function(x) { 
       lapply(b, function(y) st_intersection( x, y ) %>% st_area() ) 
     })

matrix(unlist(l), ncol = length(b), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] 4.00 2.16    0
# [2,] 2.16 4.00    0
# [3,] 0.00 0.00    4
```

**calculate overlapping percentage**

```
l2 <- lapply( b, function(x) { 
  lapply(b, function(y) st_intersection( x, y ) %>% st_area() * 100 /sqrt( st_area(x) * st_area(y) ) ) 
})

matrix(unlist(l2), ncol = length(b), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  100   54    0
# [2,]   54  100    0
# [3,]    0    0  100
```